# Intersecting three rays and a sphere of known radius

Tags: geometry, numerical-methods

So I actually solved this problem using an iterative solver, but it annoys me because as far as I can tell it should be possible to do it directly.

I have three known 3D "rays" that all start at the origin, and are represented as three unit vectors $a$, $b$, and $c.$

I know that these three rays all touch the surface sphere of known radius $R$ (without intersecting the interior of the sphere). So the task is to find the center position of the sphere $p$.

For this to have a solution the three rays all point more or less in the same direction which I know they do by construction in my case (in fact, in my specific case I happen to know that the $z$ component is $<0$ for $a, b$ and $c$). I also know that the sphere is "in front" of all thee rays (and does not contain the origin.. i.e. $p.p > R^2$)

I thought this would be easy to solve, just set up the distance from the point to each ray and set it to be equal to $R$, then manipulate and solve for $p$, but alas I could not manage to isolate any sensible expression for $p$. I then tried both Maple and Mathematica and was unable to solve it there either (in fact, Mathematica just hangs indefinitely). This leads me to believe I'm not properly stating this problem.

As I mentioned, I was able to solve this iteratively (gauss newton) but it just kind of bugs me so I was hoping maybe someone could have a stab and show me how to do it, maybe I'll pick up some tricks for next time.

Comment: I know how to solve it in theory, but I can't seem to actually solve it in practice :(
The problem is that a,b,c are not points, they're rays - which means that each of y our A, B and C above include p in the expression (e.g. A is p projected onto a), so it just gets super messy and I can't even set it up in a way that mathematica can solve so I must be missing some key trick that makes it possible to solve this.

Comment: sorry I didn't get what you know. you only know $R$ and that three given rays intersect the sphere ? in that case there are of course many solutions. hence I thought you knew the intersection points

Comment: I know three specific rays that touch the surface of the sphere, and R. I don't know the center point of the sphere. I think the reasoning below about the planes seems promising so I'm going to have a go with that.

Comment: (and a ray is a starting point and a direction,  not a starting point and a ending point)

Comment: I don't know the three points, I just know the rays. I.e. a*s touches the sphere, but I know a, not s (knowing s requires knowing p, but I don't know p either). There's clearly enough information to work it out, I just can't figure out how to manipulate things to get p to fall out.

Comment: There should only be one solution because I know the radius of the sphere.

Comment: @user1952009 There are not three rays pointing from three different starting points ("3 people"). They all start at one point.

Comment: @user1952009 Example: the three rays are the positive $x$, $y$, and $z$ axes; $R=\sqrt2$. A solution is $p=(1,1,1)$. Tell me another solution.

Comment: I finally understood, honestly that was highly unclear (what you knew : that "without intersecting the interior of the sphere" meant "tangent")

Comment: @user1952009 "touch the surface" was a pretty good clue. After all, "tangent" is from the Latin _tangere,_ "to touch." :-) But it's good we cleared up the point of confusion.

Comment: in that case, I'd start by showing that the 3 tangent points are at the same distance to the origin. by taking the mean of the 3 unit directions, we get a ray toward the center the sphere, and it reduces to finding what point of that ray is at a distance $R$ to the tangent 3 rays (a problem of distance between a point and a ray), it can be easily solved as said DavidK, no quadratic or polynomial equation is involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given three unit vectors $a$, $b$, and $c$ and the radius $R$ of a sphere
tangent to all three of the rays in the directions of $a$, $b$, and $c$ from the origin.

We desire to find the unknown center $p$ of that sphere.

There is a plane $\pi_1$ through the origin and through $p$
such that the unit vectors $a$ and $b$ are mirror images of each other
through $\pi_1$.

In fact the plane $\pi_1$ is just the plane through the origin
perpendicular to $b - a$.

Likewise, if $\pi_2$ is the plane through the origin perpendicular to
$c - a$, then $a$ and $c$ are mirror images of each other through $\pi_2$
and $\pi_2$ passes through $p$.

The planes $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ intersect in a line that passes through
the origin and through $p$. By finding the sine of 
the angle between this line and one of the vectors $a$, $b$, or $c$, 
and using the fact that the origin, one of the points of tangency,
and $p$ must form a right triangle, you can find the distance
from the origin to $p$, and since you know the direction from the origin
you can find the point exactly.

For the actual calculation, you can use some vector arithmetic,
for example a vector along the line from the origin to $p$ is
$v = \pm (b - a) \times (c - a)$,
and you can use 
$\lVert v \times a \rVert = \lVert v \rVert \lVert a \rVert \sin \theta_{va}$
to find the sine of the angle $\theta_{va}$ between $v$ and $a$.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a solid plan! I'll give this a go!

Comment: @user1952009 And nothing else. I've edited the answer to list the given information explicitly.

Comment: hence you can't locate the sphere since there are many solutions

Comment: @user1952009 I'm not seeing your "many solutions". There are multiple spheres of radius $R$ tangent to the three _lines_ through the origin parallel to $a$, $b$, and $c$, but "rays" means only half the line is valid, and that eliminates all but one possibility.

Comment: FWIW, this method worked perfectly!

Comment: SO you know that the 3 rays are tangent to the sphere !!!! lol, not that they intersect the sphere

Comment: Yes, I stated as much in the original question ("I know that these three rays all touch the surface sphere of known radius R (without intersecting the interior of the sphere)").

Comment: I was so caught up with just analytically manipulating the expressions that this really simple geometric interpretation didn't occur to me. Very nice!